# Zabbix 3.4.15 discovery trigger: how to add discovery parameter {#SERIAL} to trigger name?

Tags: triggers, zabbix, discovery

I have a discovery for attached Android phones with triggers for each phone becoming disconnected more than 2 minutes, and more than 10 minutes.

The discovery request returns this sort of thing:

```
{"data": [
   {"{#STATUS}": "device", "{#SERIAL}": "ad0717021c0042fa80"},
   ...
   {"{#STATUS}": "offline", "{#SERIAL}": "ad07170216aa8a8b69"}
]}
```

The trigger template looks like this:

```
Name: {#SERIAL} disconnected >10m
Expression: {android_device_basic:adb.is_available[{#SERIAL}].sum(10m)}=0
```

In the expression, it seems that {#SERIAL} is correctly working: when I disconnect a phone, the trigger shows up, but I want the name to say which phone is involved.

I've tried replacing {#SERIAL} in the name with $1 and {ITEM.VALUE}, but all show up literally instead of being replaced with the serial number. (I thought $1 should at least have shown up as 0, but ho-hum.)

What should I replace {#SERIAL} with?

Comment: Could you paste  a sample output of your discovery and the key of the item and trigger prototype? I suppose that {#SERIAL} should be the macro returned by it, but if it isn't expanded to the real value then something is missing.

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni Hi, I think I've added what you've asked for in the question. SERIAL works in the expression, but not in the name.

Comment: I've doublecheched some of my templates and your setup should work. As you pointed out, {#SERIAL} exists and it's expanded in the expression evaluation: the issue with the expansion in the name seems like a bug. You are already on the latest 3.4, could you upgrade to 4.0 ?